# Iterating over multiindex dataframe (Python) and assigning dicts to index-value pairs

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am at my wit's end with this... I have a dataframe of three columns (aff_id, mkt and bkgs) I grouped by two of them (aff_id and mkt) :

```
df_gb_aff = df.groupby(["affiliate_id", 'mkt']).sum()
df_gb_aff.sort('bkgs', ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

to give me a multiindex dataframe that looks a bit like this:

```
                                bkgs
aff_id          mkt 
2508b863a1a4    bcab9d6ec630    1910.707124
6cc5f0e8c96b    b7d0dbd38376    1374.924684
188e238326e4    446bb566f202    1206.589522
                dbe759c691eb    1203.979908
6cc5f0e8c96b    0e9013464c4c    1203.532310
```

What I want to do now is to iterate over each aff_id, and make a dict of mkt (key) - bkgs (value) pairs, but since each aff_id value has different mkt values, Python throws an error when a df_gb_aff.loc[index_1, index_2] doesn't exist.

I've been getting the indexes with these:

```
aff_list = df_gb_aff.index.levels[0].values
mkt_list = df_gb_aff.index.levels[1].values
```

and trying to iterate over with:

```
for i in aff_list:
    for j in mkt_list :
       print df_gb_aff.loc[i,j]
```

Anyone have a sensible way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with dict comprehension:

```
d = {idx[1]: df_gb_aff.ix[idx][0] for idx in df_gb_aff.index}

print (d)
{'446bb566f202': 1206.589522, 
'bcab9d6ec630': 1910.7071239999998, 
'0e9013464c4c': 1203.5323100000001, 
'dbe759c691eb': 1203.979908, 
'b7d0dbd38376': 1374.9246840000001}

print (d['bcab9d6ec630'])
1910.707124
```

And if need loop `Multiindex`:

```
for idx in df_gb_aff.index:
    print (idx)
    print (df_gb_aff.ix[idx])

bkgs    1910.707124
Name: (2508b863a1a4, bcab9d6ec630), dtype: float64
('6cc5f0e8c96b', 'b7d0dbd38376')
bkgs    1374.924684
Name: (6cc5f0e8c96b, b7d0dbd38376), dtype: float64
('188e238326e4', '446bb566f202')
bkgs    1206.589522
Name: (188e238326e4, 446bb566f202), dtype: float64
('188e238326e4', 'dbe759c691eb')
bkgs    1203.979908
Name: (188e238326e4, dbe759c691eb), dtype: float64
('6cc5f0e8c96b', '0e9013464c4c')
bkgs    1203.53231
Name: (6cc5f0e8c96b, 0e9013464c4c), dtype: float64
```

Comment: d = {idx: df_gb_aff.ix[idx][0] for idx in df_gb_aff.index} is exactly what I was looking for. nice!